# env не является внутренней или внешней

Tags: python, scrapy

нашел на просторах интернета парсер, склонировал его, перешел к репозиторию.

Ввел команду `scrapy crawl spiders`, парсер запустил и выдал ошибку `Environment variable PARSA_TOKEN not set`

Затем ввел команду env `PARSA_TOKEN=123 scrapy crawl spiders`

И выдает `env не является внутренней или внешней программой....`.

Что делать?
Я работал в окне Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

Даже не знаю, тянет ли это на ответ...

Если у вас Debian || *buntu (и прочее Debian-based), выполните (от рута):

```
apt-get install python-pycurl
```

затем

```
cp /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycurl* ~/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Comment: у меня windows.